# Best way redirect REST service request on glassfish + JAX-RS to https URL?

Tags: rest, glassfish, jax-rs

I have implemented a REST service on glassfish4 + JAX-RS. Now I want use a https connection for authentication.

The URI for http is http://myhost/myapp/services/rest/myservice and for https is https://myhost_2/myapp/services/rest/myservice. I want prevent the usage of http://myhost/myapp/services/rest/myservice.

I think one way is redirect a request over http://myhost in the REST JAX-RS class to https://myhost_2. Is this a good way? How can I implement this?

Comment: I believe you could answer requests to http with 301 (Moved permanently, telling the client to use the new location in future requests) pointing to the https equivalent in the location header of the response.

Comment: left as answer in case it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could answer requests to *http* with `301` (Moved permanently, telling the client to use the new location in future requests) pointing to the *https* equivalent in the location header of the response.

Comment: not right away. I could imagine that the paths will not match exactly in any case, so there would be the most work to do. For the rest you would just need to respond with 301. You also could use a single servlet on the http container that responds to everything (`/*`) with 301. You wouldn't need to modify the rest of the application. Or on top move this to an apache httpd that enables you to shut down the http-glassfish.